# Difficulty in running RMI Java

Tags: java, rmi

I have one client, one serverClient and another ServerFin. serverClient in the middle for different operations between client and serverFin. My code works as intended  on localhost.

My problem is that I have to put the two servers in the same dir (compiled with javac and rmic) and then start rmiregistry. This way it works fine. I want to run each of these two servers from their original folders (still on localhost). I have tried a few things but I get the usual java.rmi.NotBoundException or other exceptions.

```
serverClient:

serverClient sC=new serverClient(cars);
Naming.rebind("//localhost/serviceOne", sC);

ServerFin:

ServerFin srv = new ServerFin (prodc);
Naming.rebind("//localhost/serviceTwo", srv);
```

I access them normally with

```
String dest = "//localhost/serviceOne";
MyClass obj =(MyClass)Naming.lookup(dest);
```

With the above; Firstly I compile ServerFin and it starts. Then, I compile with javac , rmic and copy-paste the stub from ServerFin to serverClient's dir. The problem arises when I start serverClient.

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxximpl_stub
```

I have tried so many things, like `Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);` but it is hopeless. It just doesn't work.

How on earth can I tell to the intermediate serverClient to connect to the registry that is running already (with ServerFin services), and store there its services as well?

Comment: I asked for a complete stack trace. That isn't it.

Comment: Give. Us. The. Complete. Stack. Trace.

Comment: Not gonna happen. I'll work around this on my own. Thanks.

Comment: If you're not going to provide complete information you should delete the question frankly, it is of zero permanent interest.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting NotBoundException with this code, you're looking up the wrong host. If the server is running on another host, you need to use that hostname in the lookup URL.

But *not* in the bind URL. That is always 'localhost'.

If you're getting another exception, you could always consider telling us what it is.

**EDIT** If you're getting `ClassNotFoundException`, there are three cases.

1. You got it when exporting your remote object. Generate the stub, or call `super(0)` instead of `super()` in your remote object constructor so you don't need one. If your remote object doesn't extend `UnicastRemoteObject`, use `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` with a port number, even zero, for the same reason.
2. You got it when binding. The Registry doesn't have the class named on its CLASSPATH. Either fix that or start the Registry from inside your server JVM, with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(),` taking care to store the result in a static variable.
3. You got it when looking up. The client doesn't have the class named on its CLASSPATH. You forgot to include it in the client JAR file, or you did something invalid like duplicating it into a different package for the client part of the project: it has to be the same class, same package, and preferably the same object code.

Comment: I didn't quite understand you post to be honest. Both servers running on my pc, the client as well. Do you mean that I just have to change my lookup? something like this: `.lookup("serviceTwo");` or `.lookup("serviceOne");` depending on what my current client needs? I am a little confused. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't get NotBoundException if everything is running on localhost. So what's your question? And I don't know what isn't clear about changing the hostname in a URL. It certainly doesn't give the result you mention here.

Comment: Sorry i ran it again, it was a different one. `java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`  I still dont get it.

Comment: Neither can anybody else get it, until you provide the real exception. Please edit the entire stack trace into your question.

Comment: You are right due to my confusion I think that I am not clear. I changed a bit my OP. Is that makes any sense now?